# Load results of LINQ join into datatable (VB.NET)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

I've seen a few examples of what I'm trying to do shown in C# but none in VB.NET.  When I try to replicate the C# examples in VB the syntax doesn't work.

I've got two datatables that I've loaded.  I need to join them into a third datatable.  Here's my code:

```
Dim foxproDataTable As New Data.DataTable = GetDataTable1() 'Load table 1 from a SQL Server db
Dim sqlServerDataTable As New Data.DataTable = GetDataTable2() 'Load table 2 from a Foxpro db

Dim joinedData = From sql In sqlServerDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                 Join fox In foxproDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                 On sql.Field(Of Integer)("SqlUserId") Equals fox.Field(Of Integer)("FoxUserId")
                 Select New With
                 {
                     .firstName = fox.Field(Of String)("FirstName"),
                     .lastName = fox.Field(Of String)("LastName"),
                     .userId = fox.Field(Of Integer)("foxUserId"),
                     .address1 = sql.Field(Of String)("Address1"),
                     .address2 = sql.Field(Of String)("Address2")
                 }

'load result datatable
Dim result As New Data.DataTable
result.Columns.Add("UserId")
result.Columns.Add("FistName")
result.Columns.Add("LastName")
result.Columns.Add("Address1")
result.Columns.Add("Address2")
Dim newRow As DataRow
For Each row In joinedData
   With result
      newRow = result.NewRow
      newRow("UserId") = row.userId
      newRow("FistName") = row.FistName
      newRow("LastName") = row.LastName
      newRow("Address1") = row.Address1
      newRow("Address2") = row.Address2
      .Rows.Add(newRow)
   End With
Next
```

When it hits the **For Each row In joinedData** line, it throws a "Specified cast is not valid" exception. If I set a breakpoint on the line and hover over **joinedData**, Intellisense identifies its type as "In-Memory Query". I've tried change it to **For Each row In joinedData.ToList()** but get the same exception.

Comment: You get the exception because at least one of the columns in the datatables is not what you think. For example you'd get this exception if you use `fox.Field(Of Integer)("foxUserId")` but that column is actually of type `String`. It has nothing to do with the `For Each`, that's just the place where the above query gets executed.

Comment: Thanks Tim!  That was exactly the problem.  I'd like to give you credit for answering the question but can't since you only posted a comment.  If you want to post an answer I'll give you credit.